# Find overlaps in time intervals by group and return subsetted data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

Say I have this dataframe, which has two IDs (1/2) with their start and end times in three different zones (A/B/C):

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), zone = c("A", 
"B", "A", "C", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "C"), start = c(0, 6, 
7, 8, 10, 0, 3, 5, 6, 7), end = c(6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 3, 5, 6, 7, 
11)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")

df

   id zone start end
1   1    A     0   6
2   1    B     6   7
3   1    A     7   8
4   1    C     8  10
5   1    B    10  11
6   2    A     0   3
7   2    B     3   5
8   2    A     5   6
9   2    B     6   7
10  2    C     7  11
```

If we look at each zone, we can visually inspect the times when IDs are in the same zone and when they are not:

```
split(df,df$zone)

$A
  id zone start end
1  1    A     0   6
3  1    A     7   8
6  2    A     0   3
8  2    A     5   6

$B
  id zone start end
2  1    B     6   7
5  1    B    10  11
7  2    B     3   5
9  2    B     6   7

$C
   id zone start end
4   1    C     8  10
10  2    C     7  11
```

e.g. Both 1 and 2 are together in zone A from 0-3, and from 5-6, but not at other times.

**Desired Output**

I want to extract three dataframes.

1. A dataframe showing the times and zones they are together:

```
  zone start end  id
1    A     0   3 1-2
2    A     5   6 1-2
3    B     6   7 1-2
4    C     8  10 1-2
```

2 & 3:  Dataframes for times when they are not together:

```
#id=1
  zone start end
1    A     3   5
2    A     7   8
3    B    10  11

#id=2
  zone start end
1    B     3   5
2    C     7   8
3    C    10  11
```

I have been trying to work with `foverlaps` from `data.table`  and the `intervals` package, but can't seem to work out the correct method.

e.g. Subsetting each zone/id, I can sort of get an output that includes overlaps, but it doesn't seem to be quite the right direction:

```
A <- split(df,df$zone)$A
Asp <- split(A,A$id)
x <- setDT(Asp[[1]])
y <- setDT(Asp[[2]])

setkey(y, start, end)

foverlaps(x, y, type="any")

   id zone start end i.id i.zone i.start i.end
1:  2    A     0   3    1      A       0     6
2:  2    A     5   6    1      A       0     6
3: NA <NA>    NA  NA    1      A       7     8
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

EDIT:  Extra example dataset that seemed to bring up some issues with current suggested solutions:

```
df2 <- structure(list(start = c(0, 5, 6, 8, 10, 13, 15, 20, 22, 26, 
       29, 37, 40, 42, 0, 3, 6, 9, 15, 20, 25, 33, 35, 40), id = c(1, 
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
       2, 2), zone = c("A", "B", "A", "D", "C", "B", "C", "B", "A", 
       "B", "A", "D", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", "B", 
       "A", "D"), end = c(5, 6, 8, 10, 13, 15, 20, 22, 26, 29, 37, 40, 
       42, 45, 3, 6, 9, 15, 20, 25, 33, 35, 40, 45)), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -24L))
          
df2

    start id zone end
 1:     0  1    A   5
 2:     5  1    B   6
 3:     6  1    A   8
 4:     8  1    D  10
 5:    10  1    C  13
 6:    13  1    B  15
 7:    15  1    C  20
 8:    20  1    B  22
 9:    22  1    A  26
10:    26  1    B  29
11:    29  1    A  37
12:    37  1    D  40
13:    40  1    C  42
14:    42  1    D  45
15:     0  2    A   3
16:     3  2    B   6
17:     6  2    C   9
18:     9  2    D  15
19:    15  2    A  20
20:    20  2    B  25
21:    25  2    C  33
22:    33  2    B  35
23:    35  2    A  40
24:    40  2    D  45
    start id zone end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to work, filtering the foverlaps output:

```
DT = data.table(df)
setkey(DT, start, end)
oDT0 = foverlaps(DT[id==1], DT[id==2])
oDT0[, `:=`(
  ostart = pmax(start, i.start),
  oend = pmin(end, i.end)
)]
oDT = oDT0[ostart < oend]

# together
oDT[zone == i.zone, .(ids = '1-2', zone, ostart, oend)]
#    ids zone ostart oend
# 1: 1-2    A      0    3
# 2: 1-2    A      5    6
# 3: 1-2    B      6    7
# 4: 1-2    C      8   10

# apart
oDT[zone != i.zone, .(id, zone, i.id, i.zone, ostart, oend)]
#    id zone i.id i.zone ostart oend
# 1:  2    B    1      A      3    5
# 2:  2    C    1      A      7    8
# 3:  2    C    1      B     10   11
```

Repeating for new input... not sure if it's correct since no expected output was provided:

```
> DT = data.table(df2)
> ...
> oDT[zone == i.zone, .(ids = '1-2', zone, ostart, oend)]
   ids zone ostart oend
1: 1-2    A      0    3
2: 1-2    B      5    6
3: 1-2    D      9   10
4: 1-2    B     20   22
5: 1-2    A     35   37
6: 1-2    D     42   45
> oDT[zone != i.zone, .(id, zone, i.id, i.zone, ostart, oend)]
    id zone i.id i.zone ostart oend
 1:  2    B    1      A      3    5
 2:  2    C    1      A      6    8
 3:  2    C    1      D      8    9
 4:  2    D    1      C     10   13
 5:  2    D    1      B     13   15
 6:  2    A    1      C     15   20
 7:  2    B    1      A     22   25
 8:  2    C    1      A     25   26
 9:  2    C    1      B     26   29
10:  2    C    1      A     29   33
11:  2    B    1      A     33   35
12:  2    A    1      D     37   40
13:  2    D    1      C     40   42
```

I suspect there is a way to pass arguments to `foverlaps` to avoid needing to define and filter by `ostart` and `oend`. As of the latest CRAN version of the package, the doc indicates that `minoverlap` is not yet implemented, so maybe it is necessary for now.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are almost there. You can try the code below by defining a function `f`

```
f <- function(A) {
    Asp <- split(A, by = "id")
    u <- na.omit(foverlaps(Asp[[1]], setkey(Asp[[2]], start, end)))
    r <- c()
    for (k in 1:nrow(u)) {
        if (u[k, end - start < i.end - i.start]) {
            p <- u[k, .(start, end)]
        } else {
            p <- u[k, .(start = i.start, end = i.end)]
        }
        r[[k]] <- p
    }
    cbind(
        zone = u[, zone],
        rbindlist(r),
        id = paste0(unique(A[, id]), collapse = "-")
    )
}
```

and then run

```
rbindlist(Map(f, split(setDT(df), by = "zone")))
```

which gives

```
> rbindlist(Map(f, split(setDT(df), by = "zone")))
   zone start end  id
1:    A     0   3 1-2
2:    A     5   6 1-2
3:    B     6   7 1-2
4:    C     8  10 1-2
```

Comment: that's awesome - thanks.  Is there a way to also be able to return the dataframes for times/zones when they do not overlap?

Comment: @jalapic I guess you can use `anti_join(df, out[, id := NULL])`, where `out` is the output in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for this, though I notice that it doesn't quite work.  For instance, say `id1` was in zone A from 29 to 37, and `id2` was in zone A from 35 to 40.  The line: ` if (u[k, end - start < i.end - i.start]) {` leads to returning the start and end times as 35 and 40, but they should be 37 and 40. I edited an example dataset into the question.

Comment: There also seems to be an issue if there are no overlaps e.g. zone C in `df2`. That could possibly be got around by adding another `if` `else` part to the loop?

Answer (score 3):

For the first data.frame, you can also use a non-equi join:

```
ovlap <- df[df, on=.(zone, id<id, start<end, end>start), nomatch=0L,
    .(zone, id2=i.id, i.start, i.end, id1=x.id, x.start, x.end)][,
        .(start=max(x.start, i.start), end=min(x.end, i.end)), 
        .(zone, id1, id2, i.start)][,
            i.start := NULL][]
#   zone id1 id2 start end
#1:    A   1   2     0   3
#2:    A   1   2     5   6
#3:    B   1   2     6   7
#4:    C   1   2     8  10
```

For the other output data.frames, you can perform a non-equi join first with the previous result and then for each interval find the sub-intervals where the other partner is not around:

```
rangeDiff <- function(DT) {
    DT[, 
        if (is.na(x.start[1L])) {
            .(start=i.start, end=i.end)   
        } else {
            .(start=c(i.start, x.end+1L),
                end=c(x.start-1L, i.end))
        }, 
        .(zone, id, i.start, i.end)][
            start<=end][,
                c("i.start","i.end") := NULL][]
} #rangeDiff

rangeDiff(ovlap[df[id==1L], on=.(zone, id1=id, start<end, end>start),
    .(zone, id, i.start, i.end, x.start, x.end)])
#   zone id V1 V2
#1:    A  1  4  4
#2:    A  1  7  8
#3:    B  1 10 11


rangeDiff(ovlap[df[id==2L], on=.(zone, id2=id, start<end, end>start),
    .(zone, id, i.start, i.end, x.start, x.end)])
#   zone id V1 V2
#1:    B  2  3  5
#2:    C  2  7  7
#3:    C  2 11 11
```

There is some inconsistency in OP where the bounds of intervals are inclusive or exclusive. I have used inclusive when both ids are around in the same zone (i.e. in the first output data.frame).

---

Edit: show output for `df2`

```
ovlap

#   zone id1 id2 start end
#1:    A   1   2     0   3
#2:    A   1   2    35  37
#3:    B   1   2     5   6
#4:    B   1   2    20  22
#5:    D   1   2     9  10
#6:    D   1   2    42  45
```

other required data.frames:

```
rangeDiff(ovlap[df[id==1L], on=.(zone, id1=id, start<end, end>start),
    .(zone, id, i.start, i.end, x.start, x.end)])
#     zone id start end
#  1:    A  1     4   5
#  2:    A  1     6   8
#  3:    A  1    22  26
#  4:    A  1    29  34
#  5:    B  1    13  15
#  6:    B  1    26  29
#  7:    C  1    10  13
#  8:    C  1    15  20
#  9:    C  1    40  42
# 10:    D  1     8   8
# 11:    D  1    37  40

rangeDiff(ovlap[df[id==2L], on=.(zone, id2=id, start<end, end>start),
    .(zone, id, i.start, i.end, x.start, x.end)])
#    zone id start end
# 1:    A  2    15  20
# 2:    A  2    38  40
# 3:    B  2     3   4
# 4:    B  2    23  25
# 5:    B  2    33  35
# 6:    C  2     6   9
# 7:    C  2    25  33
# 8:    D  2    11  15
# 9:    D  2    40  41
```

df2 sorted by zone for easier checking:

```
    start id zone end
 1:     0  1    A   5
 2:     6  1    A   8
 3:    22  1    A  26
 4:    29  1    A  37
 5:     0  2    A   3
 6:    15  2    A  20
 7:    35  2    A  40
 8:     5  1    B   6
 9:    13  1    B  15
10:    20  1    B  22
11:    26  1    B  29
12:     3  2    B   6
13:    20  2    B  25
14:    33  2    B  35
15:    10  1    C  13
16:    15  1    C  20
17:    40  1    C  42
18:     6  2    C   9
19:    25  2    C  33
20:     8  1    D  10
21:    37  1    D  40
22:    42  1    D  45
23:     9  2    D  15
24:    40  2    D  45
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggested answer.  I tried it with a similar dataset (`df2` in the edited question), and it did not seem to work. Is there something I should change to make it generalizable?

Answer (score 3):

**Updated Solution**
I have made some modifications to the previous solution so that it works with the newly presented data set `df2`:

- I tried to create all combinations of `id == 1` and `id == 2` in every zone to try and find their intersects
- Then I created a custom function to take a subset of our data set plus a pair of `id`s to extract their `start` to `end` values so that we have two vectors and we can find their intersects easily
  ` In the end I applied this function to every subset of our data set

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

fn <- function(data, x, y) {
  base::intersect(data %>%
                    filter(row_number() == x) %>%
                    select(start, end) %>%
                    {map2(.$start, .$end, ~ .x:.y)} %>%
                    unlist(), 
                  data %>%
                    filter(row_number() == y) %>%
                    select(start, end) %>%
                    {map2(.$start, .$end, ~ .x:.y)} %>%
                    unlist())
}
```

Then we apply it on our data set:

```
split(df2, df2$zone) %>%
  map(~ .x %>% 
        mutate(grp = row_number()) %>%
        {expand.grid(.$grp[.$id == 1], .$grp[.$id == 2])} %>%
        rowwise() %>%
        mutate(insec = list(fn(.x, Var1, Var2))) %>%
        filter(length(insec) != 0) %>%
        unnest(cols = c(insec)) %>%
        group_by(Var1, Var2) %>%
        filter(row_number() == 1 | row_number() == n()) %>%
        filter(n() > 1) %>%
        mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
        pivot_wider(names_from = id, values_from = insec) %>%
        ungroup()) %>%
  keep(~ nrow(.x) != 0) %>%
  imap_dfr(~ .x %>% 
             mutate(zone 
                    = .y) %>%
             select(!starts_with("Var"))) %>%
  relocate(zone) %>%
  rename(start = `1`, end = `2`)

# A tibble: 6 x 3
  zone  start   end
  <chr> <int> <int>
1 A         0     3
2 A        35    37
3 B         5     6
4 B        20    22
5 D         9    10
6 D        42    45
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  It does seem to work on the example dataset, but doesn't seem to generalize to other similar datasets e.g. `df2` in the edited question - I'm not sure exactly why

Comment: @jalapic I have made some modification to the previous solution so it now works with `df2`. Would you please check it on your original data set and let me know if there is more improvement I need to apply on this.